# How to filter to multiple paths using functional programming

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I have the following pseudo-code:

```
let array = getData();
array.filter(x => condition1(x)).doSomething1...
array.filter(x => condition2(x)).doSomething2...
array.filter(x => condition3(x)).doSomething3...
```

Obviously this is not efficient because it iterates the array 3 times.

I was wondering if I there is a way to do something like:

```
array.filterMany([
    x => condition1(x).doSomething1...,
    x => condition2(x).doSomething2...,
    x => condition3(x).doSomething3...
])
```

So that the array gets iterated only once?

Comment: Can you provide a more clear examples ?

Comment: Use array reduce.

Comment: Couldn't you just use logical "and" `&&`?

Comment: @clabe45 I would like to do different things depending on the condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use array reduce functionality.

For example:

```js
    const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
    
    const split = arr.reduce(([odd, even], current) => {
        if (current % 2 === 0) {
           even.push(current);
        } else {
           odd.push(current);
        }
    
        return [odd, even];
    }, [[], []]);
    
    console.log('Odd / Even', split);
```

Comment: Thank you. I can only except in 7 minutes

Comment: Happy to help @MotKohn :-)

Comment: If there's a chance that the same value could satisfy multiple conditions, be sure to turn that `if/else` into a series of `if`s!

Comment: @shabs sure. That is a great idea.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```js
const condition1 = x => x === 1;
const condition2 = x => x === 2;
const condition3 = x => x === 3;

[1, 2, 3].map(n => {
  condition1(n) && console.log('foo');
  condition2(n) && console.log('bar');
  condition3(n) && console.log('baz');
})
```

Comment: What do you expect the `.map` function to do?

Comment: @Neal nothing more than a `forEach`! perhaps that would've been more semantically precise.

Answer (score 1):

You could take the conditions into an array and check against with [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

```
var conditions = [condition1, condition2, condition3],
    filtered = array.filter(a => conditions.every(c => c(a)));
```